# Can't see templates in Visual Studio 2015 for .net Core Class Library Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I can't add anything to my .net Core Class Library project. Template window is empty.

What I have tried: 
1) Reinstall  .NET Core 1.0.1 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2
2) Clearing templates cache (ItemTemplatesCache, ProjectTemplatesCache) in Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE and running

```
.\devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates
.\devenv.exe /Setup
```

EDIT:
Repairing Visual Studio also didn't help. 
EDIT 02. march 2017:
Reinstalling Windows didn't help. I thing templates somehow breaks after installing tools for debuging azure function.

Comment: @MegaTron There is no target framework when you are adding file in Visual Studio. You can see target framework only when creating project. I have created Class Library for .net core. And now I want to create new class, but I can't because template window is empty while trying to 'Add New Item'

Comment: Do you have vs2015 update 3 installed?

Comment: Ofc, I had it working before, problems started when I had to install all stuff for debuging azure function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I had to install VS 2017 for my .net core apps. I am sure now that in my case Azure SDK 2.9 was causing the problem.

Comment: Anyway you should use VS2017. The tooling for VS2015 remains preview and is less likely to be updated any more.